How to downgrade Visual Studio to use .NET SDK 8 again?
I have Visual Studio 2022 installed with and without preview, but it seems they all use .NET SDK 9.0 since I upgraded. This turned out to be a terrible decision as since it keeps using old versions of nuget packages. I tried modifying the installation to remove the SDK or also the runtime. But removing the runtime deletes essential Visual studio features.
.NET SDK 8 is not listed in the individual components. Even though I have it installed outside of VS, apparently that's not good enough.
Having uninstalled .NET SDK 9 with VS, it's no longer listed as an installed program in Windows.

"Even though I have it installed outside of VS, apparently that's not good enough" this is confusing as it should be "good enough". If you have installed .Net 8 on your machine (or .Net 6, .Net 7, .Net 9) then you can create projects targeting any of these using VS - usually you pick the target when you create a new project (there is no need to do anything really in terms of installing/uninstalling/modifying VS2022 itself).

Well, actually I could be wrong in terms of you might need an upgrade to VS2022 to work with .Net 9 ... but in any case, you certainly should be able to target .Net 8 even if you have installed the most recent version of VS supporting .Net 9.

.NET 9 was released last week (12th November 2024). If you have installed any updates to VS 2022 since then it will likely offer you the ability to create projects with .NET 8 by default. This doesn't stop you changing that to .NET 8 though.

All my projects still target .net8.0, that never changed. This has to do with how visual studio builds those projects. Something went wrong with that, it loads the wrong version of nuget packages. So I want to downgrade to before that upgrade.
'net8.0'
